# Here im Using AngularJs when my data in div why my total amout not counting

Tags: angularjs

**Here why my total amt not counting**

```
<div ng-controller="MyHomeCNtrls">
    <div id="CountdataWithinhTheDiv">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Id</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Quentity</td>
                <td>Price</td>
                <td>Total</td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="pr in Prodt">
                <td>{{pr.productId}}</td>
                <td>{{pr.ProductName}}</td>
                <td>{{pr.quantity}}</td>
                <td>{{pr.Price}}</td>
                <td>{{pr.Total}}</td>
                <td>Total: {{ getTotal() }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**AngularCode**
**Service**
     this.Gymser = function () {
 var xx = $http({ url: '/Home/Prodt', method: 'Get',params: JSON.stringify(),
 content: { 'content-type': 'application/Json' } }) return xx;}

**controller**

```
 function PropertyData() {
        var xxx = Myservice.Gymser();
        xxx.then(function (d) {
            $scope.Prodt = d.data;
        })
    }
```

**AngularCode For Counting**

```
 $scope.getTotal = function () {
 var total = 0;for (var i = 0; i < $scope.Products.length; i++) {
   var product = $scope.Products[i];total += (Product.price * Product.quantity);}return total;}
```

Comment: Post your controller

Comment: this.Gymser = function () {
        var xx = $http({
            url: '/Home/Prodt',
            method: 'Get',
            params: JSON.stringify(),
            content: { 'content-type': 'application/Json' }
        })
        return xx;
    }                                                                                                    function PropertyData() {
        var xxx = Myservice.Gymser();
        xxx.then(function (d) {
            $scope.Prodt = d.data;
        })
    }

Comment: Post in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see your controller having Function named `getTotal()`

You should have defined in the controller,

```
   $scope.getTotal = function(type) {
        var total = 0;
        angular.forEach($scope.items, function(el) {
            total += el[type];
        });
        return total;
    };
```

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/CHBm8RCqW5RNZWrzAe5r?p=preview)

Comment: im not getting total amt